# Не показывать кнопку, если она уже нажималась

Tags: android

Не показывать кнопку, если она уже нажималась в этом приложении в предыдущих запусках к примеру. Схожий принцип с cookie. Никак не могу реализовать.

Comment: ну  так запоминайте, что уже нажали (напрмер, в настройках). И блокируйте кнопку. Тем более, Вы уже задавали подобный вопрос.

Comment: перестаньте уже спрашивать глупости, которые в гугле за 30 сек находятся.

Comment: Имеется ввиду при остальных запусках приложения. Нашёл бы - не спрашивал бы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первым навыком, которым должен обладать программист является умение повторно использовать код (будь то чужой, или свой). Что бы использовать чужой код, нужно найти его. гугл в этом к счастью помогает. Именно по этому нужжно первым делом научиться гуглить. Что бы нагуглить решение, его нужно привести к как можно более общему виду. В вашем случае вам нужно сохранять значение перманентно, то есть между запусками программы. То есть хранить подобие "настроек приложения". Вот и возьмите ваш вопрос, приведенный к общему виду, и переведите на буржуйский язык. получится что-то вроде **android store settings**, что и вбиваем в поиск в гугле. И, о, чудо, первый же результат как раз то, что надо!!

Comment: Ха +1 однозначно! Можно так ответить на 70% вопросов сразу. А некоторые особо наглые еще и обижаются, когда за них погуглят, на каждое их требование по ссылке выставят, а они пишут дескать там и сами погуглить можем. Раз можете так погуглите, блин.

Comment: @Gleb Kuznetsov , мне погуглить не влом, просто вечно за них ни кто не будет гуглить, или останутся они на уровне практикантов навсегда...     
Я пытаюсь показать, каким образом можно научиться самому это делать.

Comment: @metalurgus , так я про автора темы. Это ему влом погуглить, соответственно и заданный вопрос на уровне питекантропа.

Answer (score -3):

Сделайте сохранение значения переменной отвечающей за статус нажатия кнопки, например в xml файле, и считывайте каждый раз, когда запускаете

Comment: так рождается говнокод. Есть SharedPreference для этого уже давным-давно.